# Communication between async tasks and synchronous threads in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am looking for the best solution for communication between async tasks and methods/functions that run in a thread pool executor from concurrent.futures. In previous synchronous projects, I would use the `queue.Queue` class. I assume that any method should be thread safe and therefore the `asyncio.queue` will not work.

I have seen people extend the `queue.Queue` class to do something like:

```
class async_queue(Queue):
  async def aput(self, item):
    self.put_nowait(item)

  async def aget(self):
    resp = await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor( None, self.get )
    return resp
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend going the other way around: using the [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) class to communicate between the two worlds. This has the advantage of not having to spend a slot in the thread pool on operations that take a long time to complete, such as a `get()`.

Here is an example:

```py
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        self._queue = asyncio.Queue()

    def sync_put_nowait(self, item):
        self._loop.call_soon(self._queue.put_nowait, item)

    def sync_put(self, item):
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._queue.put(item), self._loop).result()

    def sync_get(self):
        return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._queue.get(item), self._loop).result()

    def async_put_nowait(self, item):
        self._queue.put_nowait(item)

    async def async_put(self, item):
        await self._queue.put(item)

    async def async_get(self):
        return await self._queue.get()
```

The methods prefixed with `sync_` are meant to be invoked by sync code (running outside the event loop thread). The ones prefixed with `async_` are to be called by code running in the event loop thread, regardless of whether they are actually coroutines. (`put_nowait`, for example, is not a coroutine, but it still must be distinguished between a sync and an async version.)

Comment: How does this work? The `asyncio` queues are not thread safe. They are meant to be used to communicate between coroutines. Since the coroutines all run in an event loop which runs on a single thread, this is why the lack of thread safety doesn't matter between coroutines. But it would matter with non-event loop code.

Comment: @bmitc The "sync_" prefixed methods use `run_coroutine_threadsafe` to run the function inside the event loop. That way, when the `self._queue.put` (and get etc) starts actually **executing**, that will be in the event loop thread.